# MVC Razor For loop binding to ViewModel problem

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-core-mvc, viewmodel

I am seeing a confusing issue with my viewmodel posting back to my controller and I  am confused as of why it is not working. Though I have an idea as of why it may not be working which I explained near the bottom.

Basically I use a for loop to bind my model to HTML in the razor view

```
           @for (int i = 0; i < Model.CheckBoxTag.Count; i++)
            {
                @if (Model.CheckBoxTag[i].TagTypeName == "test")
                {
                    ....
                }
            }
```

When I submit the form, the test CheckBoxTag objects are sent to my controller as expected.

However, when I do the same further down the html page only using the Escalation tags:-

```
            @for (int i = 0; i < Model.CheckBoxTag.Count; i++)
            {
                @if (Model.CheckBoxTag[i].TagTypeName == "test1")
                {
                        ...
                }

            }
```

The test1 CheckBoxTag objects are not sent back to the controller. (The count is still 3, whereas it should be 6)

The fact it's the same code I am unsure how to tackle it.

My theory: I believe it is not posting back to my controller because the test for loop are the 1st elements in the collection, therefore it always goes into the IF. Whereas the test1 objects are near the bottom of the collection so therefore the IF is skipped quite a few times in the loop.

Is that correct? If not, what could be the issue?

Thanks

Comment: Collection indexers must start at zero and be consecutive (unless you include an input for the indexer). Your `if` blocks mean that your are probably not generating consecutive indexers. You need to show the data in the view (in particular the value of the `TagTypeName` property

Comment: Your indexes will overlap

Comment: @StephenMuecke I thought so, though your explanation is a lot more concise  than mine. Thanks for confirming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the comments section, the indexers must be consecutive.

Therefore in the for loops I put

```
     @for (int i = 0; i < Model.CheckBoxTag.Count; i++)
        {


            @if (Model.CheckBoxTag[i].TagTypeName == "test1")
            {
                // New!
                <input type="hidden" name="CheckBoxTag.Index" value="@i" />
                    ...
            }

        }
```

So now the indexers "[i]" are now being incremented on every loop

Comment: Better to just add a `<input type="hidden" name="CheckBoxTag.Index" value="@i" />` in each loop

Comment: Should be inside the `if` block :)